# how to know the progress of each thread?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qthread

im new in python and i have created an uploading program with multi threading, my problem is i have only one progress bar that displays the progress of each thread.
im using python pyqt4 QThread.
Is there a way to know whats the progress of each uploading thread?
here are some parts of the code.

```
class Worker(QThread):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self,parent)
        self.counter = 0
        self.received = 0
        self.size = 0
        self.f = None
        self.ftp = None
        self.filename = ""

    def __del__(self):    
        self.wait()

    def handleDownload(self, block):
        self.counter += 1
        self.received += len(block)
```

the handleDownload() will then emit signal to the progress bar to update its value.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a counter object that's shared between all threads.  Each time a thread completes a download it locks with a [QMutex](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qmutex.html) increments the count and unlocks you can then send your signal and modify the progress bar(although you may want to make sure it doesn't update too often)

Comment: as i understand it, if i upload multiple file simultaneously, the progress bar will only be updated when one of the file is uploaded? Most of the file is higher than 600mb. Is  there a way to get or to print the percentage of each upload? thx adrew for the reply :). i found an [artile](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/01/python-threads-and-the-global-interpreter-lock/) about python thread that is very useful

Comment: you've got the content length... and your probably writing each block... as the saying goes... do the math